# TCP client readStringUntil only when data exists

Tags: wifi, communication, web-server, networking, tcpip

I have the attached script that reads data from a socket server (it is PHP at the server end).

My problem (I think) is that the `readStringUntil()` needs a test above it, so that it "reads up to \r" **only if there is any data** being received, otherwise it seems to keep trying to read forever, because when I DO send data, it is received with 1-2 seconds delay.

If I constantly send (properly \r delimited) data without any pause, then it seems to be received instantly (10-20ms or so).

I tried: `if (client.available()) { String received_message = client.readStringUntil('\r'); }` but it doesn't seem to be the right function, doesn't do anything.

This is ESP32 board, compiler mentioned it found **two wifi libraries**, one in arduino folder and one in ESP32, it used the second one. This might be relevant to what functions are available.

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "MyWiFi";
const char* password =  "1234";

const uint16_t port = 8080;
const char * host = "myserver.example.com";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("...");
  }

  Serial.print("wifi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {

  WiFiClient client;

  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    Serial.println("connection to host failed");
    delay(500);
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("connected to server");

  // I assume this is where I need a test like "if any received data exists" >>>

  String received_message = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(received_message);
  

  // intentional delay doesn't seem to do much 
  // when it constantly tries to read for data that is not always there
  delay(100);

  // do I need to disconnect here ?!
  // client.stop();
}
```

**EDIT:** my PHP loop looks like this:

```
do{
    $accept = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incomming connection");

    // $message_to_send = 'hi there '.microtime(true)."\r";
    // OR 
    // get message from memcached variables
    
    if($message_to_send!=''){
        
        echo "\nsending: ".$message_to_send;
    
        socket_send($accept, $message_to_send, strlen($message_to_send), MSG_OOB);
    }
    
} while (true);
```

Comment: esp WiFi libraries close the connection when the last WiFiClient object which referenced it is destroyed. so here at the end of the loop().

Comment: does the server send data immediately after you connect to it? you send no request

Comment: You mean that is when it closes it automatically or when I need to call the close ? Thanks.

Comment: Server sends data immediately if I tell it to, it is inside an infinite loop where I make it check for new data and send it if found. The delay appears when it looped with no data to send and then it started sending something.

Comment: If the loop constantly sends properly delimited data on each cycle (e.g `'hi there '.microtime(true)."\r")`, then there is no delay.

Comment: your client connects and disconnects in every loop(). make WiFiClient global, connect it back only when it disconnects. and then will `if (client.available())` work

Comment: You mean the `client.connect` in top of the loop causes the delay ? I don't think is that because if I comment-out the `client.readStringUntil()` then it loops much faster.

Comment: Do I move `WiFiClient` right above the `loop(){}` to make it global ? And I don't know how to connect it back when it disconnects :/

Comment: `client.readStringUntil()` waits a second for the data. if the server sends the data immediately after the connection from client is established, then the  readStringUntil would catch it. if it sends the data later, the connection is already closed. `if (!connected) connect`

Comment: I don't know how to use the `connected` code you mentioned.

Comment: then you need project guidance and not an answer on a Q&A site. https://forum.arduino.cc/

Comment: I posted a topic exactly there under project guidance yesterday, nobody replied :/

Comment: I don't see it there.